# how add new column with column names based on conditioned values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table that contains active cases of covid per country for period of time. The columns are country name and dates.

I need to find the max value of active cases per country and the corresponding date of the max values.  I have created a list of max values but cant manage to create a column with the corresponding date.

I have written the following loop, but it returns only one date (the last one - [5/2/20]):

```
for row in active_cases_data[column]:
    if row in max_cases:
        active_cases_data['date'] = column
```

[screenshot of df and resulting column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Bpi.png)

table looks like this:

| country | 4/29/20 | 4/30/20 | 5/1/20 | 5/2/20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Italy | 67 | 105 | 250 | 240 |

I need extra column of date for the largest number for the row(in Italy case its the 5/1/20 for value = 250) like this:

| country | 4/29/20 | 4/30/20 | 5/1/20 | 5/2/20 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Italy | 67 | 105 | 250 | 240 | 5/1/20 |

Comment: what's the index of your data? could you include a part of your dataframe into the question instead of showing half of it in an image?

Comment: Hi! I know, that you are new here. It would be much easier for people who might help you to add sample of data as text - we must recreate your case to test it, so it would  reduce the totally unnecessary workflow from our side.

Comment: thank you for your comments and patience. I am new here and learning :)

Answer (score 1):

In pandas we are trying not to use python loops, unless we REALLY need them.

I suppose that your dataset looks something like that:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Country": ["Poland", "Ukraine", "Czechia", "Russia"],
      "2021.12.30": [12, 23, 43, 43],
      "2021.12.31": [15, 25, 40, 50],
      "2022.01.01": [18, 27, 41, 70],
      "2022.01.02": [21, 22, 42, 90]})

#   Country 2021.12.30  2021.12.31  2022.01.01  2022.01.02
#0  Poland  12          15          18          21
#1  Ukraine 23          25          27          22
#2  Czechia 43          40          41          42
#3  Russia  43          50          70          90
```

Short way:

You use idxmax(), after excluding column with name:

```py
df['Date'] = df.loc[:, df.columns != "Country"].idxmax(axis=1)

#   Country 2021.12.30  2021.12.31  2022.01.01  2022.01.02  Date
#0  Poland  12          15          18          21          2022.01.02
#1  Ukraine 23          25          27          22          2022.01.01
#2  Czechia 43          40          41          42          2021.12.30
#3  Russia  43          50          70          90          2022.01.02
```

You just have to be aware of running this line multiple times - it tooks every column (except of excluded one - "Country").

Long way:

First, I would transform the data from wide to long table:

```py
df2 = df.melt(id_vars="Country", var_name = "Date", value_name = "Cases")

#   Country Date        Cases
#0  Poland  2021.12.30  12
#1  Ukraine 2021.12.30  23
#2  Czechia 2021.12.30  43
#3  Russia  2021.12.30  43
#4  Poland  2021.12.31  15
#...
#15 Russia  2022.01.02  90
```

With the long table we can in many different ways find the needed rows, for example:

```py
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=["Country", "Cases", "Date"], 
                      ascending=[True, False, False])

df2.groupby("Country").first().reset_index()

#   Country Date        Cases
#0  Czechia 2021.12.30  43
#1  Poland  2022.01.02  21
#2  Russia  2022.01.02  90
#3  Ukraine 2022.01.01  27
```

By setting the last position in `ascending` parameter you could manipulate which date should be used in case of a tie.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I have tried to use 'idxmax' and got error, but the long way(not so long) had worked perfectly!!! :) :) :)

Comment: Didnt work in the end. I need a list with largest cases, date af that case and country. the melt function worked just fine. but the problem is I want to groupby country and choose the max values for cases and display the  co rresponding date for that case. but it gives me an error : 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute' - for sorting values, for reset index and for nlargest...

Comment: OK, could you create another question or edit out this one? Because it is totally different thing than the one described by you in this question.

Comment: I have managed to solve it. I have created a list with max cases. used melt function for the table. Then I used a query to extract the rows with max cases country and date: max_cases = melt_df.query('cases in max_cases_list')